# How to get the Eva Field of a content type in hook_preprocess_node using entity_metadata_wrapper?

Tags: theming, hooks, entities

There are two content types called `A` and `B` in my website and there is an entity reference from B to A. I created an `EVA views` which displays information of both `A` and `B` and it works well. because there is an entity reference from `B` to `A`, an `EVA Field` has been added to the `manage display` of content type `A`. here it is (content type `album` equals to `A` and `sub-album` equals to `B`):

[image]

I'm going to theme the nodes of `A`, this is my code :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables){
switch ($variables['node']->type){

    case 'album':
            $suggest = "page__node__album";
            $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $suggest;
            $wrapper =  entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
            $variables['title']= $wrapper->title->value();
            $variables['field1']= $wrapper->field_album_field1->value();
            $variables['field2']= $wrapper->field_album_field2->value();
            break;

}
```

}

this code saves fields of content type in `$variables` array but I don't know how to get the `EVA Field` which is attached to the content type `A`. How do I can get that as variable?

Comment: Looking at the code quickly, EVA doesn't implement any of the hooks from the entity API module, so you won't be able to use it with a metadata wrapper currently

Comment: There is a field in `kpr()` that returns `eva` but I hoped if I could use metadata wrapper.

Comment: Yes you'll see it on the plain `stdClass` object, unfortunately EVA doesn't implement [`hook_entity_property_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info/7) or [`entity_hook_field_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/entity_hook_field_info/7), so `EntityMetadataWrapper` doesn't know that field exists